# How to get from Wroclaw airport to the main train station?

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, wroclaw

I am landing at 22:40 and I wanna ask if there is some night bus going to the main train station (Wrocław Główny)? My train is going at 5:00 at the morning, so I have time.

Answer (score 6):

Your last bus  406 is at 11.14 p.m. do not miss this bus because this is theoretically the last bus.

There is also the night bus number 249 at 0:23. but you will arrive to the main station in 2 hours.

Answer (score 4):

- city bus, line 406 - ticket 3.00 PLN (~0.73 €) - last stop called "Dworzec Główny PKP"
- night bus, line 249 - ticket 3.20 PLN (~ 0.78 €) - last stop called "Dworcowa"

Buses are generally equipped with terminals where you can get your ticket using your credit card. Don't forget you need to validate it in the machine later.
There are also boards displaying current stop. Both will take half-hourish to get to train station.

- taxi - normally around 50 PLN (~ 12 €), but nightly tariff can make it around 70 PLN.

You can check your timetable [here](http://wroclaw.jakdojade.pl/). Type "Port Lotniczy" as "Z" and "Dworzec Gł. PKP" as "Do".

Answer (score 3):

I found this [Website about Wroclaw](http://wikitravel.org/en/Wroc%C5%82aw) and it's written that

> From the airport, bus 406 operates from the terminal building to
>   central Wrocław between 5am and 11pm every 20 minutes. There is also a
>   night bus 249 . The night bus will take approximately one hour to get
>   to the city center.

I hope this will help you